# Jquery: Perform function when user comes out of focus

Tags: jquery, function, focus

I need to perform a function when a user comes out of focus. So far I can do it when they go into focus but how do I do it the other way round:

```
 $("input.default-value").focus(function() {
                 $(this).css("color", active_color);        
                                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

```
$("input.default-value").focus(function() {
       $(this).css("color", active_color);        
 }).blur(function() {
       $(this).css("color", inactive_color);     
});
```

Of course, i'd recommend using classes to add the css.

```
.default-value.active { 
   color: #FF0000;
} 

$("input.default-value").focus(function() {
           $(this).addClass('active');        
     }).blur(function() {
           $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    });
```

but i digress..

(and if you don't care about ie7 and under, you can use the :focus pseudo-class)